# cancel query from spark sql jdbc statement cancel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

1. we want to use `statement.cancel` to cancel execution
2. My problem is: I use `statement.cancel`,but web ui show the query is still  executed
3. is there any way to cancel running query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're operating through the Thrift server (which I assume you are, since you mentioned JDBC), it looks like this was recently (June 2015) [resolved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6964). It is slated for the 1.5.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

Through the web-ui you can kill the running stage and effectively kill the job (which could also be done programmatically if you know the job id). I haven't looked into other ways to cancel a running query.